# Message discussion query

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, eloquent, query-builder

I try to create a discussion system that display messages between two users ordering by time *like the image* using SQL, for example if user 10 want to see his messages with user 45, this is my table structure:

**Messages( id(PK), sender_id(FK_USER), receiver_id(FK_USER), subject, content,created_at,updated_at);**

I tried this sql query but it doesn't show what i want:

```
select s.id,
       s.subjet,
       d.source_id as `source`,
       d.id,
       d.subject 
 from messages s,
      messages d
where s.destination_id=d.source_id 
  and d.source_id=s.destination_id 
  and s.source_id=202 
order by created_at asc;
```

[image: Example]

Comment: in your table structure you don't have column called `destination_id` or `source_id` ??

Comment: is the same (destination_id => receiver_id and source_id => sender_id) @pratikgarg hope you find solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your table structure and requirement correctly, you can try something like below -

```
SELECT *
  FROM MESSAGES
 WHERE SENDER_ID IN (10, 45)
   AND RECEIVER_ID IN (10, 45)
 ORDER BY CREATED_AT
```

Or like this -

```
SELECT *
  FROM MESSAGES
 WHERE (SENDER_ID = 10 AND RECEIVER_ID = 45)
    OR (RECEIVER_ID = 10 AND SENDER_ID = 45)
 ORDER BY CREATED_AT
```

by default ordering will be done in ASC fashion so no need to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a select case (i have leaved all the column for demo)

```
 select s.id, 
    case s.sender_id when 202 then s.subject else '' end, 
    case s.receicer_id when 202 then s.subject else '' end, 
    s.subject, s.content, s.created_at
from message s
where s.sender_id = 202
order by s.created_at ASC
```

Comment: There is a syntax error somewhere in your code I can't find it (I check it but can't find it)

Comment: you have where condition on sender_id = 202.
then how receiver_id (second case statement) will be having same value>?